# Generate url for Django Simple History historical object

Tags: django, django-simple-history

Given an model called `Stuff`, I want the url to a `HistoricalStuff` object.

In other words, how does one implement `get_historical_url` in the below code snippet?

```
stuff = Stuff.objects.first()
stuff.pk
-> 100
historical_stuff = stuff.history.first()  # we want to get url for this
historical_stuff.pk
-> 1
get_historical_url(historical_stuff)
-> /path/to/admin/stuff/100/history/1
```

Obviously the dumb solution would be to use a format string but I'd rather use urlresolvers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much digging around, I found in the simple history source code that the url name is similar to the admin change names, namely `admin_%s_%s_simple_history`.

With this knowledge, `get_historical_url` looks like

```
def get_simplehistory_url(history_obj):
    parent_obj = history_obj.history_object
    return urlresolvers.reverse('admin:{}_{}_simple_history'.format(
        parent_obj._meta.app_label, parent_obj._meta.model_name), args=(parent_obj.id, history_obj.pk))
```